# Creating an array from localstorage containing strings ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I put a useState as value in the localStorage:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ room: "", canBook: 0 , hasBooked: 0});


  localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(user));
```

In another component i wish to assemble the array again in order to check if certain conditions are met:

```
 const bookSlot = () => {
let userDetails = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
// some code to parse the string to an array

if (userDetails.canBook != 0) { //this doesn't work
  return userDetails;
 }
};
```

My question is, how do i parse the `userDetails` string to an array?

Comment: Do you want to parse to an array or to an *object*?

Comment: What exactly should be the end result?

Comment: my bad, i'm still new to this. I would like to parse it to an object, otherwise i wont be able to use dot notation like `userDetails.canBook` right?

Comment: Yeah. You can't access `canBook` property of a string (`getItem` returns a string) because it doesn't exist. I posted an answer on how to parse it to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method and pass the JSON string retrieved from the local storage (`localStorage.getItem("userDetails")`) as its first argument:

```js
let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails"));
```